# Parse XML File for a number and display in textbox

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, xml-parsing

**My Program:** Contains two textBoxes and one XML file on the desktop.
[image]

**XML File:**[image]

**My Goal:** I want to parse XML File and display the desired values in the textBox. First number **123456** from XML File will be displayed in the first texBox. Similarly, Second number **9876** from XML File will be displayed in the second texBox. Rest, everything should be ignored in the XML File.

I tried to Google search for a simple example that will help me understand how to parse  XML file and display in textbox but I couldn't find any such simple program example. This program will help me learn this technique quickly and easily, and your help will be much appreciated! Thanks!! :)

Comment: You should learn LINQ to XML.

Comment: SO is full of examples (70K questions tagged as xml)

Comment: Did my answer work for you did you understand? If so please tick the marker.

Comment: @CarlPalsson i dont see your answer but thanks for checking. Answer by QtX works. Thanks again. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dict = XDocument.Load(fname)
            .Descendants("field")
            .ToDictionary(f => f.Attribute("name").Value, 
                          f => f.Attribute("value").Value);

firstNumberTextBox.Text = dict["first_number"];
secondNumberTextBox.Text = dict["second_number"];
```